# Water maintains an equal level in connected vessels

Tags: terminology, water, fluid-statics

Water maintains an equal level in connected vessels.

What is this property called?

Answer (score 1):

I never heard any specific name for this property. It's just a consequence of Pascal's law and the fact that the pressure field is continuous at the surface of the liquid (water pressure = atmospheric pressure).

Answer (score 0):

The law/principle of [connected/communicating vessels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_vessels).